# qgis2web python error message

Tags: python, error, qgis2web

I've experienced at times that the qgis2web plugin does not work. I have received this python error message:

Ha ocurrido un error mientras se ejecutaba el código de Python:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/u54202/.qgis2/python/plugins\qgis2web\qgis2web.py", line 51, in run
    dlg = MainDialog(self.iface)
  File "C:/Users/u54202/.qgis2/python/plugins\qgis2web\maindialog.py", line 55, in __init__
    self.previewMap()
  File "C:/Users/u54202/.qgis2/python/plugins\qgis2web\maindialog.py", line 97, in previewMap
    MainDialog.previewOL3(self)
  File "C:/Users/u54202/.qgis2/python/plugins\qgis2web\maindialog.py", line 222, in previewOL3
    previewFile = writeOL(self.iface, layers, groups, popup, visible, json, cluster, labels, params, utils.tempFolder())
  File "C:/Users/u54202/.qgis2/python/plugins\qgis2web\olwriter.py", line 53, in writeOL
    exportLayers(layers, folder, precision, optimize, usedFields)
  File "C:/Users/u54202/.qgis2/python/plugins\qgis2web\utils.py", line 60, in exportLayers
    reducePrecision = re.compile(r"([0-9]+\.[0-9]{%s})([0-9]+)" % str(int(precision)))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''


Versión de Python:
2.7.4 (default, Apr  6 2013, 19:54:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]


Versión de QGIS:
2.8.2-Wien Wien, 1b929ef

Ruta de Python: ['C:/PROGRA~1/QGISWI~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\\processing', 'C:/Users/u54202/.qgis2/python/plugins\\postgis_geoprocessing', 'C:\\Users\\u54202\\.qgis2\\python\\plugins\\GeoCoding\\libs', 'C:/PROGRA~1/QGISWI~1/apps/qgis/./python', u'C:/Users/u54202/.qgis2/python', u'C:/Users/u54202/.qgis2/python/plugins', 'C:/PROGRA~1/QGISWI~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\bin\\python27.zip', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\bin', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win32.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\python_dateutil-2.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pytz-2014.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win32.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\six-1.6.1-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\wx-2.8-msw-unicode', u'C:/Users/u54202/.qgis2//python', 'C:\\Users\\u54202\\.qgis2\\python\\plugins', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\qgis\\python\\plugins\\fTools\\tools', 'C:\\Users\\u54202\\.qgis2\\python\\plugins\\mmqgis/forms', 'C:\\Users\\u54202\\.qgis2\\python\\plugins']
```

The other day a solved this problem from the python console but today is not working:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings
QSettings().remove("Extent")
QSettings().remove("Base layer")
QSettings().remove("Template")
```

Edit:

OK, It worked... but again I have the same problem: python error. But this time this syntax does not worked.

Why is this still happening?

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/u54202/.qgis2/python/plugins\qgis2web\qgis2web.py", line 51,
>   in run
>       dlg = MainDialog(self.iface)   File "C:/Users/u54202/.qgis2/python/plugins\qgis2web\maindialog.py", line
>   55, in **init**
>       self.previewMap()   File "C:/Users/u54202/.qgis2/python/plugins\qgis2web\maindialog.py", line
>   99, in previewMap
>       MainDialog.previewLeaflet(self)   File "C:/Users/u54202/.qgis2/python/plugins\qgis2web\maindialog.py", line
>   229, in previewLeaflet
>       previewFile = writeLeaflet(self.iface, utils.tempFolder(), 500, 700, 1, layers, visible, "", cluster, "", "", "", labels, 0, 0, json,
>   params, popup)   File
>   "C:/Users/u54202/.qgis2/python/plugins\qgis2web\leafletWriter.py",
>   line 203, in writeLeaflet
>       if str(field) == "icon_exp": UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xed' in position 1: ordinal not in
>   range(128)
>
> Versión de Python:
>   2.7.4 (default, Apr  6 2013, 19:54:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
>
> Versión de QGIS:
>   2.8.2-Wien Wien, 1b929ef
>
> Ruta de Python:
>   ['C:/PROGRA~1/QGISWI~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing',
>   'C:/Users/u54202/.qgis2/python/plugins\postgis_geoprocessing',
>   'C:\Users\u54202\.qgis2\python\plugins\GeoCoding\libs',
>   'C:/PROGRA~1/QGISWI~1/apps/qgis/./python',
>   u'C:/Users/u54202/.qgis2/python',
>   u'C:/Users/u54202/.qgis2/python/plugins',
>   'C:/PROGRA~1/QGISWI~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\bin\python27.zip',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\DLLs',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\bin',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win32.egg',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\python_dateutil-2.2-py2.7.egg',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytz-2014.2-py2.7.egg',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win32.egg',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\six-1.6.1-py2.7.egg',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode',
>   u'C:/Users/u54202/.qgis2//python',
>   'C:\Users\u54202\.qgis2\python\plugins',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\qgis\python\plugins\fTools\tools',
>   'C:\Users\u54202\.qgis2\python\plugins\mmqgis/forms']

Comment: Sorry, I forgot. I have the latest version, since today. Still not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do the same in the console, but add qgis2web/ before each param name, eg:

```
QSettings().remove("qgis2web/Extent") QSettings().remove("qgis2web/Base layer") QSettings().remove("qgis2web/Template")
```

Since that error was caused by Precision, also try:

```
QSettings().remove("qgis2web/Precision")
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! My problem is solved! I guess the key was add "qgis2web". Thanks again

Comment: Ok, I understand now. Sorry, I did not know

Answer (score 4):

Ah, this looks like an encoding error. I need to patch the plugin to replace `str()` with `unicode()`. I'm away for two weeks, so for the moment, change leafletWriter.py line 203 from:

`if str(field) == "icon_exp":`

to:

`if unicode(field) == "icon_exp":`

Do the same with any similar errors. And if it works, please do create a pull request on Github.

Edit: it's worth naming your layers and properties with simple characters only. There are probably other bits of code which will fail with eg accented characters.

Comment: I've committed this change to master, but I've not tested it yet. Try that and let us know if that fixes the problem.